# How to center oEmbedded content

Tags: filters, hooks, formatting, css, oembed

I understand you have to paste the link that you're embedding without any code wrapping around it, but how do I force the embedded content to be centered? Currently, the default is aligning to the left.

I could modify the core file, but it's highly discouraged, so I'm asking to see if there's any hook or filter to get around this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some Googling, I found a solution that was originally done for a Twitter embed, but I modified it to work with all oEmbed contents. Keep in mind that for this to work on existing posts, you'll need to do an "update" for the oEmbed content to refresh from the cache.

```
add_filter('oembed_result','center_oembed',10,3);
function center_oembed($html, $url, $args) {
    $html = '<p style="text-align: center;">' . $html . '</p>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: FWIW it would probably be better to use .alignleft .aligncenter and .alignright to match the caption/image classes, since you'll probably want your objects to display similarly and it should already work in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty CSS fix I came up with for Twitter oEmbed (`.entry-content` is specific to the theme):

```
.entry-content > iframe {
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Seems to work, YMMV.